# visual studio don't understand statements location on files containing big comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

When the code file contains a lot of comments in different locations and in big blocks of lines, visual studio become unable to detect the lines correctly for compiler errors and for breakpoints when I remove these comments it work fine.

I faced this problem in the visual studio 2010 and now in 2012

I'm talking about c++ language files

Is this known behaviour in visual studio with C++ or not and how to fix it

Comment: I have never ever seen this in the ~20 years that I have used Visual Studio.

Comment: Do comments by any chance have some local characters - it may be encoding related then.

Comment: I comment using vassistx, I select the code and press *, then it surround it with /**/, I say it again this happen only with large amount of lines for example 1000 line of code. this is strange and this happened only after installing vassistx but I didn't think it will cause any problem, the file that had the problem is .cpp of 3382 lines it works fine after I removed more commented blocks, this happens with large files only that what happened with me really the debugger or the error window when I double click an error sometimes put me on an empty line.

Comment: Are you sure that the file with comments was not changed after the last successful build? I see breakpoints not matching up to the code when a file is changed but for some reason the dll, lib or exe was not rebuilt when I ran the debugger. When that happens I sometimes will put an intentional syntax error in the file and see if I get errors while compiling.

Comment: @drescherjm : yes that was after the successful build directly.